# Compare wrong inserted values in target SQL Server table with source table values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, target and source. Somehow data in the target table is wrongly calculated and I want to see which data is not the same as in the source table.

For example I have target table T  here I have columns

```
BetSlipId int, ExternalId int, IsValid bit
```

In source table S i have

```
BetSlipId int, ExternalId int, Invalid bit
```

isValid in target is calculated as ~ ISNULL(S.Invalid,0)

How can I find out which `isValid` flag is different for `ExternalId` in my target table?

```
select FSBT.ExternalSettleId
FROM #FSBTempTable FSBT
join IGP.SportsbookManagement.Settle S on s.ExternalSettleId= fsbt.ExternalSettleId
where FSBT.IsValid <> ~ S.Invalid
```

Here is an example only for non null values

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
Select t.ExternalID 
from target t 
inner join source s on t.externalID = s.ExternalID 
where s.isValid <> t.isValid
```

Explanation:

the query is joining target and source table on the basis of external id and returns target table's `externalId` which `isValid` column value is not same as `isValid` value in source

Update:
As you said, in source table there is invalid column which is null in case of valid so

```
ISNULL(s.invalid)
```

will give 1 for valid and 0 for invalid and you want to compare it with isValid column of target table ( which will be 1 for valid and 0 for invalid ), So where condition should be :

```
WHERE ISNULL(s.invalid) <> t.isValid
```

Comment: @user2171512 let me know if my solution works for you or need any changes

Comment: One more thing. I have in source table field Invalid(is NULL in case of valid otherwise 1) and in target table (column isValid) i handle this as ~ ISNULL(Invalid,0)  . How to compare this values ?

Comment: Can you add schema of tables and query you have tried

Comment: @user2171512 did my updated answer worked as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join on two columns which have common values in source and target tables like below:

```
-- Both the queries assume is target's IsValid is null then it means 0, otherwise 1
select t.* from tgt t
  join src s on t.BetSlipId = s.BetSlipId and t.ExternalId = s.ExternalId
where isnull(t.IsValid, 0) = isnull(s.InValid, 0)
```

(OR)

```
select t.* from tgt t
  join src s on t.BetSlipId = s.BetSlipId and t.ExternalId = s.ExternalId
where isnull(t.IsValid, 0) <> case when s.InValid = 1 then 0 else 1 end
```

DB Fiddler is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79211b81796699a2cb35008c5ff1c94a)

If you provide sample data, then we can assist further.